# Can Superset visualize data returned from a REST API call?

Tags: apache-superset, druid

We are trying to use Apache Superset to visualize business data, some of which is stored in SQL based databases, but some of it (think for example of external weather data) we need to access via public APIs (normally REST, but also sometimes push based microservices like websockets and gRPC).

Can Superset surface data in this way, or is it tied to SQL or SQL-like queries/APIs?

Answer (score 9):

Superset supports any database engine with a DB-API driver and SQLAlchemy dialect (https://superset.apache.org/#databases).

So, in theory, you could wrap your API calls into some custom-developed SQLAlchemy accessible endpoint, but unless you need access to data that's refreshed in real-time, your best bet is probably to [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) the data from these public APIs into some type of reporting data lake.